# 3d cone and cylinder in R

Tags: r

How do you draw 3d cone and cylinder in R? I think you are using wireframe but I cannot find any examples anywhere. I am trying to do things that Matlab and Mathematica are ususally used to do. If drawing 3d objects can be done as easy as those programs, I would really like R.

Comment: `cone3d` is in the rgl-demos.

Comment: Thank you very much for the direction. Is there anyway to do it not by using rgl? I didn't think it is that hard, you know. But I don't see any examples.

Answer (score 3):

This is how Jaakko Nevalainen and Deepayan Sarkar did it with lattice From : 
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-April/196715.html

```
library(lattice)

A<-matrix(ncol=2, nrow=64)

for(i in 0:63) {  A[i+1,1]<-sin(i/10)  
A[i+1,2]<-cos(i/10) }

Sigma<-matrix(c(0.5,0.1,0.1,0.25),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2) 
G<-eigen(Sigma)

E1<-t(G$vector%*%t(A)) 
E2<-t(diag(sqrt(G$values))%*%t(E1)) 
mu<-c(0.1,0.2) 
E3<-sweep(E2,2,-mu)

a<-sqrt(max(rowSums(sweep(E3,2,mu)**2))) 
b<-sqrt(min(rowSums(sweep(E3,2,mu)**2)))

astar<-as.numeric(a+abs(mu[1])) 
bstar<-as.numeric(b+abs(mu[2]))

xstar<-seq(-astar,astar,len=50) 
ystar<-seq(-bstar,bstar,len=50)

g<-expand.grid(x=xstar,y=ystar)

p1<-2*g$x*mu[1]/a**2+2*g$y*mu[2]/b**2 
p2<-(g$x**2/a**2+g$y**2/b**2) 
p3<-mu[1]**2/a**2+mu[2]**2/b**2-1

q<-(p1+sqrt(p1**2-4*p2*p3))/(2*p2) 
z<-sqrt(1-(q*g$x)**2-(q*g$y)**2) 
zstar<-(z/q) 
ind0<-!(q<1) 
g$z<-zstar 
sc<-matrix(c(rep(c(-1,-1,-1),sum(ind0))),nrow=sum(ind0),byrow=TRUE) 
gstar<-rbind(g[ind0,],sc*g[ind0,])

group<-c(rep(1,nrow(gstar)/2),rep(2,nrow(gstar)/2)) 
gstar$group<-group
gstar <- g 
gstar$z[!ind0] <- NA 
gstar$z2 <- -gstar$z 
wireframe(z + z2 ~ x * y, gstar, colorkey=TRUE,drape=TRUE, scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

[image]